# Input overflowed

Tags: python, pyaudio

I have the problem of input overflowing and I can't figure out how to manage it.
So let me give you my code and explain it:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=1, rate=SAMPLERATE, input_device_index=chosen_device_index, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(SAMPLERATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    decoded = np.frombuffer(data, 'int16')
    mfcc_feat = mfcc(decoded, samplerate=SAMPLERATE/3, winlen=WINDOW_SIZE, winstep=WINDOW_STEP, nfft=NFFT)    
    if len(frames) < 299:
        frames.append(mfcc_feat)        
    elif len(frames) >= 299:
        predict_test = tf.convert_to_tensor(frames)
        result = model.predict(predict_test)
        frames = []
        frames.append(mfcc_feat)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

So basiclly what I'm doing here is to using a trained tensorflow model to predict on audio features, that are generated in realtime.

First I open up a stream. Then I read the audio data in that stream using a for loop. This happens when I set the samplerate to 48000 and the chunk size to 192 excatly 250 times a second.
So 250 times a second I read in the next chunk, decode it using `numpy.frombuffer` and then calculating the features. The features are stored in the array `frames`. Each time, the length of the `frames` array is `299`, i will use this array to predict with my tensorflow model.

And there is the problem:

Since the `for` loop iterates 250 times a second, each iteration has `0.004` seconds to complete, otherwise, the input of the stream will overflow (`data = stream.read(CHUNK)`). When I just calculate the features in each iteration, this gets done faster than 0.004 s and the input does not overflow. Since the model prediction takes more than 0.004 seconds, the input overflows.

What can I do so that the prediction of my model gets done every 299 iteration steps, without letting the next for loop iteration wait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of preventing `stream.read(CHUNK)` from throwing an overflow error is to pass to it `exception_on_overflow = False`. Such that:

`data = stream.read(CHUNK,exception_on_overflow = False)`

`exception_on_overflow = False` does not stop the IOError but allows the program to ignore it. This should allow the program to continue working saving data to `mfcc_feat` even if your model takes too long.

Source [PyAudio Documentation](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.Stream.read)